# Return value of the const pointer in the function

Tags: c++, constants

I am using a `const` member function in a class.

Here is the syntax that I am using:

```
const Grid2D<T>* GetSlice(uint32_t z) const {
   return &(GetTSlice<Grid2D<T>>(z));
}
```

Here is the syntax of `GetTSlice`

```
template<class G>
    G GetTSlice(uint32_t z)
    {
        return (G*)(*this)[z];
    }
```

> '`G Grid3D<T>::GetTSlice<Grid2DReloaded<T>>(uint32_t)`' : cannot convert '`this`' pointer from '`const Grid3DReloaded<T>`' to '`Grid3D<T> &`'

Any idea what I could be doing wrong ?

Comment: You're right, there's something wrong. But for a _better_ question, can you explain how you decided that?

Comment: I want to return a const pointer and am not sure how to do it.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. We can _already_ see what you're trying to do, so repeating that is not helpful.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you're trying to do. Can you post the definition of `GetTSlice`?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Heh, didn't mean to contradict you. :-P

Comment: @Tomalak, I am sorry, this is the information I could give by looking at the header file declaration. I am not an expert unfortunately.

Comment: @Kiran: It does not take a C++ expert to form a precise question.

Answer (score 3):

The function `GetTSlice` returns a `G` by signature, but you try to return a `G*`. Either change the function's return type to a pointer or return an object, whichever is appropriate to your intended design.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning the address of a temporary object, which is going to be destroyed once you leave the function.

Although adding error message or some such may turn out helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that's the issue? Look at the method's return type, and compare it to the returned expression. I think `GetTSlice` is supposed to be another method, and if so, it's probably supposed to return by reference.

Comment: No, I'm not sure, it's just the likeliest explanation I could come up with having this little input.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other already reported problems (pointer to temporary object, G* instead of G):
method GetTSlice should be also `const` - otherwise you could not call it from the const methods like GetSlice.

Answer (score 1):

To add one more problem to the pile: the return type should be `G const` (or `const G` if you prefer) and the cast on the return should also include the `const` cast:

```
template<class G>
G const GetTSlice(uint32_t z)
{
    return *( (G const *)(*this)[z] );
}
```

The above should resolve *most* of the other problems.  Check to make sure that the operator `[]` is also `const` otherwise, that will be another source of trying to mutate a constant.